# Error 8100030d when update to Live Messenger 2011

Tags: msn, msn-messenger

I've tried solutions in http://messenger-support.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!8B3F39C76A8B853F!13937.entry

and others search out from Google, none of them works.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this thread is still active but had the same issue and just found out that changing the MTU (Maximum Transmission Unit) size (to 1492 in my case) resolves the sign-in problems in Live Messenger 2011 (both the 8100030d and 81000306 errors).

The MTU size can be changed :

1. On the router
2. Using [DrTCP](http://www.dslreports.com/drtcp) (optional)